# $\{b_n\}$ is a complex sequence for which $\sum_n a_nb_n$ converges whenever $\{a_n\}\in \ell^p$, then $\{b_n\}\in \ell^{p'}$

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis

Let $p$ be such that $1<p<\infty$ and $p'$ be its conjugate exponent.  Show that if $\{b_n\}$ is a complex sequence for which $\sum_n a_nb_n$ converges whenever $\{a_n\}\in \ell^p$, then $\{b_n\}\in \ell^{p'}$.

So we must be careful here because we do not know if the map $\{a_n\}\mapsto \sum_n a_nb_n$ is a bounded linear functional. So I Instead, look at the partial sums operators $\{a_n\}\mapsto \sum_{n=1}^N a_nb_n$ which I KNOW to be bounded linear maps. But I'm trying to figure out how to compute their norm, because if I do that then maybe I can apply the Uniform Boundedness Principle. Can somebody help me out here? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your way of thinking is correct: Let $T_N$ be the $N$-th partial sum operator. To compute the norm, do this: First of all $|\sum_{n=1}^Na_nb_n|\leq\sum_{n=1}^N|a_nb_n|\leq(\sum_{n=1}^N|a_n|^p)^{1/p}\cdot(\sum_{n=1}^N|b_n|^{p'})^{1/p'}\leq\|(a_n)\|_p(\sum_{n=1}^N|b_n|^{p'})^{1/p'}$, which is true by the famous [Holder inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder%27s_inequality), so $\|T_N\|\leq(\sum_{n=1}^N|b_n|^{p'})^{1/p'}$.

Conversely, set $a=(a_1,\dots,a_N,0,0,0,\dots)\in\ell^p$, where $a_i=|b_i|^{p'-2}\overline{b_i}$ when $b_i\neq0$ and $a_i=0$ when $b_i=0$.

Now note that $$\|T_N\|\geq\frac{1}{\|a\|_{\ell^p}}|T_N(a)|=\frac{\sum_{n=1}^N|b_n|^{p'}}{\bigg(\sum_{n=1}^N|b_i|^{pp'-p}\bigg)^{1/p}}=\frac{\sum_{n=1}^N|b_n|^{p'}}{\bigg(\sum_{n=1}^N|b_i|^{p'}\bigg)^{1/p}}=\bigg(\sum_{n=1}^N|b_n|^{p'}\bigg)^{1/p'}.$$

(the calculations with $p,p'$ all follow from the condition $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{p'}=1$).
You know what to do afterwards!

Comment: So, the norm is pointwise bounded, so it is uniformly bounded, so the sequence converges to show that $\{b_n\} \in \ell^{p'}$? Is that right?

Comment: @MSV Exactly. We have $(T_N)\subset {\ell^p}^*$. Also, for any $x\in\ell^p$, $|T_Nx|$ is bounded. By principle of uniform boundedness, $\|T_N\|$ is a bounded sequence. But this shows exactly that $\|b\|_{p'}<\infty$, which is what we want.

Comment: Yeah, I realized how to fill in the gaps, couldn't edit my comment for a few mintues >.< Thanks man you are the bomb!!!

Comment: @HaKuNaMaTaTa Hahah, glad I could help.